# VueJS vee-validate issue when passed validation as props to input component

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vee-validate

I'm building an input component to work with **vee-validate**.

 for more convenience, I want to use validation rules as a props for this.

Every thing is ok when I use `v-model directive` on parent. but, with `value` property; after writing in the field and validating, input value reset to it's parent.

This is logical? if not, how can I solve this problem without `v-model`?

> **Note that**:
>   
>   1) - Validations events are **'input'** and **'blur'**
>   
>   2) - I never want to set `v-on:input` event on parent

[See This Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jj89198103/0rdd70zq/1/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is logical. 
`@input="$emit('input', $event.target.value)"` is useless here because you don't listen to the input event.

When your input is invalid, component is re-render again. `value` of input component has never change changed when you input. When it re-render, it will display correct value which is passed from parent.

https://jsfiddle.net/787g7q0e/

Comment: Thanks bro. However, perhaps the only way to handle it, is to use `data` option on component like this: `localValue: this.value`, which will be updated on native input event. Is there a better idea?

Comment: The solution above solves the problem, [Updated Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jj89198103/787g7q0e/2/). but why all input component re-redered after inputing any of them? Because of injection?